# How to extract the buffer data while recording videos in CameraX Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camerax

I am just facing a small issue while recording videos in **CameraX** using "Video Capture", I don't want to directly write the data into a file, instead, I wish to extract the buffer data, do some actions on it and then write that into a file.

How do I extract the buffer data of the video?

I would be obliged if someone could help me with this